# Parallel proccessing in R doParallel foreach

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I have written a script that runs fine, but it doesn't not appear to be doing the parallel processing.  I tried changing the cores from 3 to 16 but the speed at which the data was being generated did not change.  Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can get this to work?

```
setwd("E:/Infections")

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(lakemorpho,rgdal,maptools,sp,doParallel,foreach,
doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(5, outfile="E:/Infections/debug.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)
x<-readOGR("E:/Infections/ByHUC6","Kodiak")
x_lake_length<-vector("numeric",length = nrow(x))
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  tmp<-lakeMorphoClass(x[i,],NULL,NULL,NULL)
  x_lake_length[i]<-lakeMaxLength(tmp,200)
  print(i)
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
df_Kodiak <- data.frame(x_lake_length)
write.table(df_Kodiak,file="E:/Infections/ByHUC6/Kodiak.csv",row.names=TRUE,col.names=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Comment: Okay, I tried the suggestions and the script runs, but again it doesn't seem like any more of the cores are being used.  I have 24 of them and the systems monitor and the rate at which the rows are being read all indicate the same speed.  I looked at the link to make reproducible and will see if I can make a spatial datafile reproducible.

Comment: > R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"
$os
[1] "mingw32"
$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"
$status
[1] ""
$major
[1] "3"
$minor
[1] "2.2"
$year
[1] "2015"
$month
[1] "08"
$day
[1] "14"
$`svn rev`
[1] "69053"
$language
[1] "R"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"
$nickname
[1] "Fire Safety"

Comment: I looked into getting the reproducible data with rdgal and the polygon sample data included only contains 2 polygons.  So I have put a small sample of my data on my website: http://researchersdilemma.com/myftp/

But if you want to use the data from rdgal....
library(rgdal)
ogrDrivers()
dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
ogrListLayers(dsn)
ogrInfo(dsn=dsn, layer="trin_inca_pl03")
polys <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="trin_inca_pl03")
writeOGR(polys, ".", "test_polys", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
getwd()  # to see where the file was put

Download est_Fetch.zip

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's usually better if we all use the built-in data, thanks for uploading that though. I'll give this a try as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I think I got it by invoking `foreach` and `%dopar%`:

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(lakemorpho,rgdal,maptools,sp,doParallel,foreach,
               doParallel)

# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------
ogrDrivers()
dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
ogrListLayers(dsn)
ogrInfo(dsn=dsn, layer="trin_inca_pl03")
owd <- getwd()
setwd(dsn)
ogrInfo(dsn="trin_inca_pl03.shp", layer="trin_inca_pl03")
setwd(owd)
x <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="trin_inca_pl03")
summary(x)

# HPC ---------------------------------------------------------------------
cores_2_use <- detectCores() - 4
cl          <- makeCluster(cores_2_use, useXDR = F)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, 9956)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores_2_use)

# Analysis ----------------------------------------------------------------  
myfun <- function(x,i){tmp<-lakeMorphoClass(x[i,],NULL,NULL,NULL)
                        x_lake_length<-vector("numeric",length = nrow(x))
                        x_lake_length[i]<-lakeMaxLength(tmp,200)
                        print(i)
                        Sys.sleep(0.1)}

foreach(i = 1:nrow(x),.combine=cbind,.packages=c("lakemorpho","rgdal"))  %dopar% (
  myfun(x,i)
)

df_Kodiak <- data.frame(x_lake_length)
```

As you can see in the screenshot below this creates an army of Rscript.exe processes using 20 of 24 CPU cores. Of course, the example data I used is small so it didn't really need all those cores, but it should serve as a proof of concept.

I never go above that ratio because if you use 100% of all CPU cores sometimes bad things happen and other server users may not be happy with you.

[image: Many CPU cores in use]

Comment: After I removed all the previous loaded data I do get an error which indicates the x-lake-length vector is not being saved.   
Any ideas? 
    > df_Test_Fetch <- data.frame(x_lake_length)
    Error in data.frame(x_lake_length) : object 'x_lake_length' not found 

Data
    ogrDrivers()
    dsn<-setwd("J:\\Elodea\\ByHUC6\\")
    ogrListLayers(dsn)
    ogrInfo(dsn=dsn, layer="Test_Fetch")
    owd <- getwd()
    setwd(dsn)
   ogrInfo(dsn="Test_Fetch.shp", layer="Test_Fetch")
   setwd(owd)
   x <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="Test_Fetch")
   summary(x)

Comment: @Jen Hey sorry I just saw your comment. Are you still having this problem? If so can you submit a new question so that it's a little easier to read and I'll work on it?

Comment: @Jen Put a comment here with a link if you do open another question so I'll be sure to see it. I can help tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Hack-R.  I have posted the question with the title
Parallel proccessing in R doParallel foreach save data

[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910490/parallel-proccessing-in-r-doparallel-foreach-save-data)

Comment: @Jen Thanks, sorry I just noticed this. I think I fixed the code.